# What is the correct transformation for "in the last three years" in indirect speech (for a particular case)?

Tags: reported-speech

This is the text I have where the phrase I want to convert to indirect speech is marked in bold.

[Wright brothers, “Letter to Carl Dienstbacht”, Dayton, November 17, 1905.](https://www.loc.gov/resource/mwright.03082/?sp=17)

> "Dear Mr. Diensbach:-
> A good deal of doubt seems to exist in Europe as to whether there is
> any truth in the reports that have been made concerning our flights of
> 1903 and 1904; and it is not at all surprising, under the
> circumstances, since there has never been any account of any one
> having seen them, except the inventors themselves. **There have been a
> number of witnesses to every flight we have made in the last three
> years**. ..."

It is evident from the context that the Wrights referred to the interval December 14-17, 1903  - November 17, 1905, which is not even 2-year long but contains the calendaristic years 1903, 1904 and 1905, three in total.

This is my attempted conversion:

On November 17, 1905, the Wrights said that there had been a number of witnesses to every flight they had made in the (**last, past, preceding, previous** ??) three years.

If I say:

- "past three years" it would mean November 17, 1902 - November 17, 1905, which is incorrect.
- "last, preceding or previous three years" I am not sure about the meaning.

The correct word has to be one that excludes 1902 and obligatory includes 1903, 1904 and 1905.

Can I leave "last three years" as it is, without changing the word "last" in order to preserve the original meaning?

Comment: _Preceding_ and _previous_ both imply 'the 3 years immediately before the date when they were writing'.

Comment: @KateBunting, Do "preceding" and "previous" imply 1902, 1903 and 1904 OR 1903, 1904 and 1905 if the Wrights wrote in 1905? If "preceding" and "previous" imply somehow the year 1902, they are not good for me.

Comment: Well, if the Wrights referred to 'the last three years' in Nov. 1905, it was a casual and not very accurate reference, since it _could_ have meant any time from Nov. 1902. You can't expect the terms I suggested to be any more exact.

Comment: You say it is evident from the context but I see no such evidence. Can you edit to clarify?

Comment: @mdewey You have to know a bit the story of the Wright brothers who started to fly powered planes (airplanes) on December 14-17, 1903. Before, they just glided. The doubts that existed were about these flights, using a motor, not the ones made before December 14-17, 1903, with gliders.

Comment: I read the sentence as one where they are deliberately covering themselves against any accusation that they may have made a flight at any time within the previous three years, either 365*3 days or three calendar years. So I agree with @KateBunting in her comments.

Comment: @mdewey, Wait, between 14-17 Dec., 1903, and October 5, 1905, the Wrights claimed over 160 powered flights made using three airplanes. I do not understand your last comment. It appears that you believe the two brothers did not make any flight in the previous or past three years relative to November 17, 1905, when they wrote the letter to C. Diensbach?!!

Comment: Sorry, left out a _not_ in the previous comment.

Comment: @mdewey, Yes, with the "not" added your comment makes sense.